# How to begin a new line in Excel during continous data logging

Tags: excel, serial-port

I'm new to programming and to finish my BA one of my "quests" is to write a programm for continous data logging from a Oxygen-Meter.
So far i managed to get the data, write them in to an excel file for a predifened time span. Unfortunately the values are always written in one row so I just see the last measure in Excel.
My question is: How do I tell my programm to put each measure into a new row?
Thanks in advance for your help and please be paitient with me I started programming 5 days ago.

```
import serial
import time
import xlsxwriter
port = "COM1"
baud = 2400
bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS
parity = serial.PARITY_EVEN
stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE
ser = serial.Serial(port, baud, bytesize, parity, stopbits, timeout=1)

while ser.isOpen():

 ser.write("O")
 time.sleep(5)              #Messung wird aller ()s abgerufen
 while ser.inWaiting()>0:

     s = ser.readline()
     Nummer = s[2:4]
     Konzentration = s[9:13] + " mg/l"
     Temperatur = s[19:23] + " °" + s[25:26]
     Temperatur2 = s[19:23]
     Zeit = s[27:32] + " Uhr"
     Datum = s[33:38] + ".2017"
     t = Nummer+" "+Konzentration +" "+Temperatur +" "+Zeit +" "+Datum

     print t

     workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook ('Sauerstoffmessung.xlsx')
     worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

     row=0 
     col=0
     seq = []
     count =  1

     rowheaders =['Nummer', 'Konzentration', 'Temperatur', 'Zeit', 'Datum']
     rowvalues = [Nummer, Konzentration, Temperatur2, Zeit, Datum]


     worksheet.write_row(row, col, tuple(rowheaders))
     worksheet.write_row(row, col, tuple(rowvalues))


     workbook.close()

 if Zeit == "08:38 Uhr":
      ser.close()
      print "Uebertragung beendet"
```

First of all thank you. Second, below is my new code. Now every new recieved measure is written in a new row, but the old ones disappear. I tried to figure it out by myself but ended up to make it worse. Is there a chance to tell the programm to keep the Data in the written row and write the next measure into the next row?

```
import serial
import time
import xlsxwriter
import io

port = "COM1"
baud = 2400
bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS
parity = serial.PARITY_EVEN
stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE
row=0
col=0

ser = serial.Serial(port, baud, bytesize, parity, stopbits, timeout=1)

while ser.isOpen():

 ser.write("O")
 time.sleep(5)              #Messung wird aller ()s abgerufen

 workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook ('Sauerstoffmessung.xlsx')
 worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

 rowheaders =['Nummer', 'Konzentration', 'Temperatur', 'Zeit', 'Datum']

 worksheet.write_row(0, 0, tuple(rowheaders))

 while ser.inWaiting()>0:

     s = ser.readline()
     Nummer = s[2:4]
     Konzentration = s[9:13] + " mg/l"
     Temperatur = s[19:23] + " °" + s[25:26]
     Temperatur2 = s[19:23]
     Zeit = s[27:32] + " Uhr"
     Datum = s[33:38] + ".2017"
     t = Nummer+" "+Konzentration +" "+Temperatur +" "+Zeit +" "+Datum

     print t

     rowvalues = [Nummer, Konzentration, Temperatur2, Zeit, Datum]

     worksheet.write_row(row, col, tuple(rowvalues))

     row += 1

 if Zeit == "08:38 Uhr":
      ser.close()
      print "Uebertragung beendet"
      workbook.close()
```

Comment: I think you may need to move the `Workbook()` create and and `workbook.add_worksheet()` outside the first while loop.

Answer (score 0):

You don't increment your row counter

```
import serial
import time
import xlsxwriter
port = "COM1"
baud = 2400
bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS
parity = serial.PARITY_EVEN
stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE
ser = serial.Serial(port, baud, bytesize, parity, stopbits, timeout=1)
row=0
col=0

while ser.isOpen():

 ser.write("O")
 time.sleep(5)              #Messung wird aller ()s abgerufen
 while ser.inWaiting()>0:

     s = ser.readline()
     Nummer = s[2:4]
     Konzentration = s[9:13] + " mg/l"
     Temperatur = s[19:23] + " °" + s[25:26]
     Temperatur2 = s[19:23]
     Zeit = s[27:32] + " Uhr"
     Datum = s[33:38] + ".2017"
     t = Nummer+" "+Konzentration +" "+Temperatur +" "+Zeit +" "+Datum

     print t

     workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook ('Sauerstoffmessung.xlsx')
     worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

     seq = []
     count =  1

     rowheaders =['Nummer', 'Konzentration', 'Temperatur', 'Zeit', 'Datum']
     rowvalues = [Nummer, Konzentration, Temperatur2, Zeit, Datum]


     worksheet.write_row(row, col, tuple(rowheaders))
     worksheet.write_row(row, col, tuple(rowvalues))

     row+=1
     workbook.close()

 if Zeit == "08:38 Uhr":
      ser.close()
      print "Uebertragung beendet"
```

Comment: Sorry i don't get it

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution yesterday but had no time to post. Tomorrow I'll upload the code. The last thing I'm struggling with is, that the csv writer seems to write every value into each excel cell with an ' at the beginning, so excel does not recognize those values as numbers and therefore doesn't create a chart.